# What medical advice can you offer for "world builders disease"

Tags: creative-writing

World builders disease is a medical condition in which a person becomes so invested and obsessed with building their world that they forget to write the story that goes with it. Their minds are so filled with great ideas but they never make it to print. Common Symptoms include obsessive attention to detail, constant re-editing, severe diarrhea , procrastination, fear of opinions, and over-analyzation.

Constant innocents have fallen prey to this horrible disease, and it is the number one killer of settings with great potential. It progresses over the course of stages, with the 4th stage being incurable. Male and female survivors report being bed-ridden for many months in excruciating agony, suffering from its debilitating side effects, forgetting to eat, sleep, or even breath. In rare cases, it can cause death.

Do you have any experience with this condition? How did you survive? What medical advice can you offer to those who have become victims of it?

Comment: +1 because of the fresh view of the syndrome, but it's still a duplicate.